# How does Input/Output Redirection work in Linux/Unix?

Tags: linux, command-line, io-redirection

Example:

> cat < test.txt

1. Is the content of the file `test.txt` written/passed to stdin of the `cat`, and then the `cat` reads its stdin?

OR

2. Does the file `test.txt` itself become the stdin of the `cat`? In other words, is the stdin of the `cat` changed to `test.txt` by setting the file descriptor (fd) of the text file to 0?

Comment: "...by setting the file descriptor (fd) of the text file to 0" -- this doesn't make sense. Files doesn't have file descriptors, processes do. With the redirection `cat` gets an fd to the file in fd 0 exactly the same way it would get an fd to the file if it were to open it itself (except that it'd get it under some other number).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option number 2: `test.txt` is opened, and `cat` is set up with its standard input pointing to that file ([the file descriptor is duplicated](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) so that it’s 0 in the process which ends up running `cat`).

On Linux, you can see this by running

```
$ touch /tmp/foo
$ sleep 120 < /tmp/foo &
[1] 3006118
$ ls -l /proc/3006118/fd
total 0
lr-x------ 1 steve steve 64 May  4 16:11 0 -> /tmp/foo
lrwx------ 1 steve steve 64 May  4 16:11 1 -> /dev/pts/3
lrwx------ 1 steve steve 64 May  4 16:11 2 -> /dev/pts/3
```

The process’ standard input is `/tmp/foo` directly.